# Setting up hot keys on Logitech diNovo keyboard

Tags: logitech-keyboard

New here - hello.  I have a fairly old Logitech diNovo keyboard. I use the Hot Keys to open different web browsers and I'm trying to set things up to be able to open Microsoft Edge. Within Setpoint I select a Hot Key and then select 'Launch Program' within 'Select Task'. Whatever I put into the box underneath 'Select Program doesn't seem to work. Has anyone got any ideas? Thank you. JeremyB

Comment: What have you put in that box? We cannot tell you what to try unless you tell what you've already tried.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have tried variations on http//: combined with www. or not, followed by Edge, Microsoft Edge, etc.  I can’t find an IP address for Edge.   J.

Comment: First, when asked to add information to your question, use the EDIT button to add the information to the question itself. Second, what does a URL or IP address have to do with opening the program Edge on your computer? You should look up how to open Edge from the command line, and perhaps study some on what IP addresses and URLs are.

Comment: Thanks again musuc2myear.  I think I'm on the wrong forum because my computer knowledge is very limited - ie I don't know what a command line is.  As you suggest, I'll do some googling and see where I go from there.  Bye.  J.

Comment: You're not necessarily in the wrong forum. I didn't suggest the preceding to make you feel badly, but to tell you the specific bits of knowledge that you can learn more about in order to better understand your own problem here. We generally work together, the askers and the community members, to get to a solution. In this specific situation you have confused some terms you may have heard places as possibly being the solution when they are not, and learning more about these topics will point you toward the solution you actually need as well as showing you what you don't need.

Comment: That is very fair comment.  Thank you.  J.